# c# Json.NET ToJson() FromJson()

Tags: c#, json.net

I understand the value of creating an external JsonConverter classes however in many cases I find it unnecessarily cumbersome.

Is there a general way to tell JSon.NET that *if* a class has a `string ToJson()` method use that for serialization and *if* the class has a `void FromJson(string json)` method use that for deserialization ?

Or/And also for immutable types *if* a class has a `static T FromJson(string json)` use that ?

Comment: Have a central static method that you build that serialises to and from JSON. Have it check for whether the `FromJson` or `ToJson` exists on the relevant type using reflection. If it does, pass in your `JsonConverter` class which invokes the `FromJson` or `ToJson` to the `DeserializeObject` or `SerializeObject` call.

Comment: Did that suggestion work for you @kofifus?

Comment: Not really, I don't want to serialize via an external method, I want it to work out-of-the-box as if the class had a JsonConverter, PErhaps I need to write a JsonConverter that does uses ToJson FromJson and decorate my class with that ?

Comment: That should certainly work @kofifus .

Comment: if I knew how to do it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a special conveter:

```
namespace Newtonsoft.Json {
  class JsonManualConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t.GetMethod("ToJson") != null && t.GetMethod("FromJson") != null;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
      objectType.GetMethod("FromJson").Invoke(new object(), new object[] { JRaw.Create(reader).ToString() });

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object o, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
      writer.WriteRawValue(o.GetType().GetMethod("ToJson").Invoke(o, new object[] { }) as string);
  }
}
```

Then we can simply do:

```
  [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonManualConverter))]
  class MyClass {
    public string ToJson() => // serialize and return json string
    static public MyClass FromJson(string json) => // deserialize and return a MyClass instance
    ...
  }
```

and Json.Net will use these methods