# Efficiently get full json string in JsonConverter.ReadJson()

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I efficiently get full json string in `JsonConverter.ReadJson()` ?

I can do:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
      var json = JObject.Load(reader).ToString(Formatting.None);
```

However that seems very inefficient as I serialize and deserialize for no reason

Any better way ?

Comment: If you only care about the JSON itself, why not drop the JsonReader and use a TextReader directly?

Comment: because I need it as part of a JsonConverter to be used as an attribute. Basically I want to use reflection of the type to an interface that have a ToJson and FromJson methods so that some of my objects can define them to serialize/deserialize in custom ways

Comment: You're not really using the converter at all in the above code.

Comment: true. I have an interface: `interface JsonMethods<T> { string ToJson(); T FromJson(string s);  }` and I want to call these methods if my class inherites this interface _and_ has my custom JsonConverter that will cann these methods

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) must fully *parse* the JSON being read so that the JSON is confirmed to be well-formed and the `JsonReader` is correctly positioned at the end of the current value upon exit.  However, it is not necessary to load the entire JSON into an intermediate `JObject` hierarchy simply to re-convert it to a JSON string.  Instead, you may be able to get better performance by using [`JRaw.Create()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JRaw_Create.htm):

```
var json = JRaw.Create(reader).ToString();
```

As can be seen in the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JRaw.cs#L61), this method streams directly from the incoming `JsonReader` to a `StringWriter` - without loading into an intermediate `JToken` hierarchy and re-serializing - by using [`JsonWriter.WriteToken(JsonReader)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm):

> ```
> public static JRaw Create(JsonReader reader)
> {
>     using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
>     using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
>     {
>         jsonWriter.WriteToken(reader);
>
>         return new JRaw(sw.ToString());
>     }
> }
> ```

The resulting `JRaw` simply encapsulates that string in its [`Value`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Value.htm).  (Of course, there is no guarantee that the resulting JSON represents an **object**, only that it represents well-formed JSON.)

Note that `JsonTextReader` will automatically recognize and parse dates and times in [common formats](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) as `DateTime` objects, and also parse floating point values as `double`.  If you need the "most literal" JSON string you may want to suppress `DateTime` recognition and/or parse floating point values as `decimal`.  The following extension method, modeled on `JRaw.Create()`, does the job:

```
public static string ReadOuterJson(this JsonReader reader, Formatting formatting = Formatting.None, DateParseHandling? dateParseHandling = null, FloatParseHandling? floatParseHandling = null)
{
    // If you would prefer a null JSON value to return an empty string, remove this line:
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        return null;
    var oldDateParseHandling = reader.DateParseHandling;
    var oldFloatParseHandling = reader.FloatParseHandling;
    try
    {
        if (dateParseHandling != null)
            reader.DateParseHandling = dateParseHandling.Value;
        if (floatParseHandling != null)
            reader.FloatParseHandling = floatParseHandling.Value;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = formatting })
        {
            jsonWriter.WriteToken(reader);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.DateParseHandling = oldDateParseHandling;
        reader.FloatParseHandling = oldFloatParseHandling;
    }
}
```

And then call it like, e.g.:

```
var json = reader.ReadOuterJson(dateParseHandling: DateParseHandling.None);
```

For details on why this may be necessary, see:

- *[Json.NET interprets and modifies ISO dates when deserializing to JObject #862](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862)*.
- *[JObject.Parse modifies end of floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26484176/3744182)*.

Comment: Thanks! I used this to write a manual json converter - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256196/c-sharp-json-net-tojson-fromjson