# Reading raw input inside JsonConverter.ReadJson

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am working on a kind of raw converter. When deserializing the decorated attribute, I need to get the raw string from the source.

```
public class X
{
  [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
  public string Y {get;set;}
}
```

`Y` will contain a serialized object, let's say `{"a":1,"b":2}`. Thus from JSON point of view the property Y will contain an object `{"Y":{"a":1,"b":2}}`. But I need it back as **exactly the same** string when deserializing.

This approach works, but takes a double load as it is deserialized and serialized back again, and it still can happen that it will be serialized in a different way.

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
  JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
  return jo.ToString(serializer.Formatting, serializer.Converters.ToArray());
}
```

What I need is something that allows me to read as raw string from the beginning till the end of a JSON object. Unfortunately, the `JsonReader` is a tokenizer, and it does the conversions right ahead while reading.

Comment: You will have to implement your own `JsonReader` subclass for that, forked from `JsonTextReader`.  Things that need preserving: 1) Whitespace formatting;  2) Numeric formatting & prevision (conversion to `double` or `decimal` and back again may tweak precision).  `DateTime` recognition can already be disabled by setting [`DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_DateParseHandling.htm) so that's not a problem.

Comment: `JsonReader` does need to tokenize the JSON to verify the JSON is well-formed but possibly a forked `JsonTextReader` could be modified to pipe the characters into some cached `StringWriter` as they are being read?  Maybe if you explain your precise requirements we could suggest an easier way?

Comment: Incidentally if you are mainly concerned with performance, `JRaw.Create(reader).ToString();` may be more performant.  See: [Efficiently get full json string in JsonConverter.ReadJson()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56945050/3744182).

Comment: @dbc It works, exactly what I needed. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Well is this a duplicate then, or do you in addition need to set `DateParseHandling.None` to prevent recognition and reformatting of date/time strings?