# C# How to save part of nested JSON into object property, but not deserialized?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, converters

This is my JSON

```
{
    "type": "user_settings",
    "created_at": 1610973280043,
    "data": {
        "user_id": 12345,
        "updated_at": "2021-01-18T15:34:40+03:00"
    }
}
```

These are my classes:

```
public class BaseMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public long CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public DataDTO Data { get; set; }

    public string DataJson {get; set;} // <-- Here I need string like this "{ "user_id": 12345, "updated_at": "2021-01-18T15:34:40+03:00" }"
}

public class DataDTO
{
    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

So I need parsed "data" (it works ok) and save nested JSON as a string (I don't know how).
Is there elegant way to save nested JSON into string property?

Something like this:

```
public class BaseMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public long CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public DataDTO Data { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyAsString("data")] // <-- This is my fantasy :)
    public string DataJson {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You must add a [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `DataJson`.  In fact this looks like a duplicate of [How can I serialize and deserialize a type with a string member that contains “raw” JSON, without escaping the JSON in the process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40529125/3744182) and [Efficiently get full json string in JsonConverter.ReadJson()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56944160/3744182), agree?

Comment: Do you really need a string? What about a parsed JObject?

Comment: Oh I see what you are trying to do -- you are trying to bind the JSON to *two properties at once* -- one a JSON string and the other the deserialized DataDTO.  There's nothing built in for that.  Suggest to use a surrogate property for one of them, as was suggested in the [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65819006/3744182) of [E. Shcherbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8715436/e-shcherbo).

Comment: @dbc Yes, this is what I was looking for. These links very helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dbc commented you can create a custom `JsonConverter` for the `DataJson` property, but you also should do something with your another property which is mapped from the `data` JSON field - `Data` of `DataDTO` type. I can propose the following solution:

**1. Custom JSON Converter (I took this from [@dbc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539360/8715436))**

```
public class RawConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
       if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
          return null;
       var raw = JRaw.Create(reader);
       return raw.ToString();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
       var s = (string)value;
       writer.WriteRawValue(s);
     }
}
```

**2. Decorate your `DataJson` property with the `JsonConverter` attribute and remove `JsonPropertyAttribute` for the `Data` property**

Note that if you don't remove the `JsonPropertyAttribute` then it won't work, since you have two properties which are mapped from the same JSON field, and as I know this is not supported by Json.NET by default.

```
public class BaseMessage
{
   [JsonProperty("type")]
   public string Type { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("created_at")]
   public long CreatedAt { get; set; }

   public DataDTO Data { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("data")]
   [JsonConverter(typeof(RawConverter))]
   public string DataJson {get; set;}
}
```

**3. Update your `BaseMessage` class so this calculates the value of the `Data` property from `DataJson`**

```
public class BaseMessage
{
   private DataDTO data;

   [JsonProperty("type")]
   public string Type { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("created_at")]
   public long CreatedAt { get; set; }

   public DataDTO Data
   {
       if (data == null)
       {
          data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataDTO>(DataJson);
       }
       return data;
   }

   [JsonProperty("data")]
   [JsonConverter(typeof(RawConverter))]
   public string DataJson {get; set;}
}
```

**Note** that I believe this is not the best solution and sure that there are other much better alternatives, but it might be feasible in your case.

Comment: This implementation works for me. Thank you so much for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use this ??

> var data  = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);

if yes, install the newtonSoft packge.