# How to serialize class to JSON, where property is of type Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Consider the following class:

```
public class ImageDataModel
{
    public JsonObject CaptureResultData { get; }
    public SmartphoneCommand SmartphoneCommand { get; }
    public LightStageCommand LightStageCommand { get; }

    public string TimeStamp { get; }

    public ImageDataModel(string _captureResultData, LightStageCommand _lightStageCommand, SmartphoneCommand _smartphoneCommand)
    {
        CaptureResultData = JsonObject.Parse(_captureResultData);
        SmartphoneCommand = _smartphoneCommand;
        LightStageCommand = _lightStageCommand;
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm.ss, dd. MM. yyyy");
    }
}
```

`SmartphoneCommand`and `LightStageCommand` are serializable objects, no problem with those. However, in the constructor, `_captureResultData` is already a serialized JSON string of type [`JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonobject?view=winrt-20348). Since I want the data in the this string to show up as serialized object data instead of a single string within my JSON file, I made it into a `JsonObject`.

The problem is, after serialization, the CaptureResult data shows up in the JSON file as follows:

```
  "CaptureResultData": {
    "android.control.afMode": {
      "ValueType": 2
    },
    "android.colorCorrection.gains": {
      "ValueType": 3
    },
    "android.control.awbMode": {
      "ValueType": 2
    },
    "android.lens.focalLength": {
      "ValueType": 2
    },
    "android.lens.focusDistance": {
      "ValueType": 2
    },
    "android.control.aeMode": {
      "ValueType": 2
    },
    "android.colorCorrection.mode": {
      "ValueType": 2
    },
    "android.colorCorrection.transform": {
      "ValueType": 3
    },
    "android.lens.aperture": {
      "ValueType": 2
    },
    "android.sensor.sensitivity": {
      "ValueType": 2
    },
    "android.sensor.exposureTime": {
      "ValueType": 2
    }
  },
```

The original string contains the correct data. How can I force the serialization to show the actual data, instead of `ValueType`?

For completeness, here is how the serialization is done:

```
using (StreamWriter jsonFile = File.CreateText(uniqueFilePaths[2]))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    };

    serializer.Serialize(jsonFile, new ImageDataModel(captureResultString, lightStageCommand, cameraCommand));
}
```

Comment: My current solution to the problem is to make the property a dictionary: `CaptureResultData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(_captureResultData);`. It works, but I guess it's just an unnecessary additional conversion step, so I don't like it.

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:json.net], but what is `JsonObject`?  It doesn't seem to be part of that library.

Comment: @dbc no it doesn't but newtonsoft is json.net.

Comment: I know that Newtonsoft is Json.NET.  But in order to help you we need to know what specifically what `JsonObject` is.  Is it [`System.Json.JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.json.jsonobject?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)?

Comment: Oh, sorry -  I misunderstood. I'm currently not at my work machine, but since I'm using the `Parse()` function it should be [Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonobject?view=winrt-20348)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET does not have any support for the types in the [`Windows.Data.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json?view=winrt-20348) namespace, so you will need to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) for [`JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonobject?view=winrt-20348) as well as [`JsonArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonarray?view=winrt-20348) and [`JsonValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonvalue?view=winrt-20348) if you ever use those classes directly.  The following should do the job:

```
public class WindowsDataJsonObjectConverter : WindowsDataJsonConverterBase<Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject>
{
    public override JsonObject ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonObject existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        JsonObject.Parse(reader.ReadOuterJson(dateParseHandling: DateParseHandling.None));
}

public class WindowsDataJsonArrayConverter : WindowsDataJsonConverterBase<Windows.Data.Json.JsonArray>
{
    public override JsonArray ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonArray existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        JsonArray.Parse(reader.ReadOuterJson(dateParseHandling: DateParseHandling.None));
}

public class WindowsDataJsonValueConverter : WindowsDataJsonConverterBase<Windows.Data.Json.JsonValue>
{
    public override JsonValue ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonValue existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        JsonValue.Parse(reader.ReadOuterJson(dateParseHandling: DateParseHandling.None));
}

public abstract class WindowsDataJsonConverterBase<TJsonValue> : JsonConverter<TJsonValue> where TJsonValue : IJsonValue
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, TJsonValue value, JsonSerializer serializer) => 
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.Stringify());
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    // Taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56945050/3744182
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944160/efficiently-get-full-json-string-in-jsonconverter-readjson
    public static string ReadOuterJson(this JsonReader reader, Formatting formatting = Formatting.None, DateParseHandling? dateParseHandling = null, FloatParseHandling? floatParseHandling = null)
    {
        var oldDateParseHandling = reader.DateParseHandling;
        var oldFloatParseHandling = reader.FloatParseHandling;
        try
        {
            if (dateParseHandling != null)
                reader.DateParseHandling = dateParseHandling.Value;
            if (floatParseHandling != null)
                reader.FloatParseHandling = floatParseHandling.Value;
            using (var sw = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = formatting })
            {
                jsonWriter.WriteToken(reader);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.DateParseHandling = oldDateParseHandling;
            reader.FloatParseHandling = oldFloatParseHandling;
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `JsonObject` implements `IDictionary<String,IJsonValue>` and `JsonArray` implements several `IEnumerable` interfaces, so Json.NET will know how to serialize these types.  it will not, however, know to deserialize them by calling the appropriate static [`Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonobject.parse?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Data_Json_JsonObject_Parse_System_String_) methods.
- There is no standard interface to indicate that a c# type should be serialized to JSON using its "raw" `ToString()` value, so Json.NET has no way to know how to serialize or deserialize `JsonValue`.
- Alternatively, you could consider replacing `JsonObject` with Json.NET's [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) in your model.  If you do, Json.NET will be able to serialize it without any conversion.

  As a second alternative, you could leave `_captureResultData` as a `string` in your data model, and mark the property with `[JsonConverter(typeof(RawConverter))]` where `RawConverter` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539360/3744182) to *[How can I serialize and deserialize a type with a string member that contains "raw" JSON, without escaping the JSON in the process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40529125/3744182)*.
- Since `ImageDataModel` is immutable, if you want to deserialize it with Json.NET you will need to create a compatible constructor and mark it with [`JsonConstructorAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm):

  ```
   [JsonConstructor]
   ImageDataModel(JsonObject captureResultData, LightStageCommand lightStageCommand, SmartphoneCommand smartphoneCommand, string timeStamp)
   {
       this.CaptureResultData = captureResultData;
       this.SmartphoneCommand = smartphoneCommand;
       this.LightStageCommand = lightStageCommand;
       this.TimeStamp = timeStamp;
   }
  ```

  Json.NET will match the JSON properties to constructor arguments using a case-invariant name match.

Mockup fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AX0Abf).